# Git HOME environment variables not being used with child-process.exec

Tags: node.js, ssh, environment-variables, exec, child-process

The second optional argument to child-process's `exec()` method are an option's object with an `env` property. This should set the environmental variables for the executable that will run, but in some cases this is not the case.

What I'm trying to do is set the HOME variable for git to use to a different path so that the host alias `MY_SSH_HOST_ALIAS` reads the `$HOME/.ssh/config` file and chooses the appropriate key for that alias. I'm trying to do this because my system's default .ssh folder is not in HOME.

However, the below fails and reads the default key from `$HOME/.ssh/`

```
const exec = require('child-process').exec

var succeeds = 'echo "my home is $HOME"' // prints my home is ~/mypath/
var fail = 'git clone MY_SSH_HOST_ALIAS:repo.git'

var options = { env: { HOME: '~/mypath/' } }

exec(fail, options, function(e, out, err) {
    console.out(e, out, err)
})
```

Comment: What if you spell out the actual path instead of using "~"?

Comment: It makes no difference, however I do get the below error when I make the HOME variable (via the options argument) `~/mypath/.ssh`, which is incorrect because ssh looks for `.ssh/` in `$HOME`. Any path that doesn't have the .ssh sub folder causes this error.

The error is, `ssh: Could not resolve hotname MY_SSH_HOST_ALIAS: Name or service not known`